# process message not called with type='headline' xmpp android

Tags: android, xmpp

I am working with XMPP chatting application and i successfully integrated the chatting using XMPP, BUT now my requirement is to handle other type of message **`type='headline'`**

So when i receive this type of message then **`processMessage`** never called.

**MMessageListener.class**

```
private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {

        public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                                   final Message message) {
            Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                    + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "message type : " + message.getType());
}


    }
```

**ChatManagerListenerImpl.class**

```
private class ChatManagerListenerImpl implements ChatManagerListener {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                            final boolean createdLocally) {
        if (!createdLocally)
            chat.addMessageListener(mMessageListener);

    }


}
```

I am stuck with this issue, please suggest

Thanks

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @HemantParmar - PLease check the updated code.

Comment: headline will never call if are on offline.

Comment: are you using any chat client library?

Comment: @SarthakMittal Yes * *smack library* *

Comment: try adding listener directly to xmppconnection object, maybe your chat listener is filtering the message.

Comment: @SarthakMittal Which method we use add as a listener.

Comment: addSyncStanzaListener() found in AbstractXMPPConnection

Comment: @SarthakMittal  I am write this code 
   connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
                Override
                public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
                }
            }, new StanzaFilter() {
                Override
                public boolean accept(Stanza stanza) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
but its not working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163796/discussion-between-sarthak-mittal-and-techvalens).